# Pass cliendid from a control as a parameter from ASP to javascript function

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a function that shows the password on a textbox and another the hides it and hows the dots.

Here's one of them:

```
function MouseOver_MudarTipoPassword() {
        document.getElementById('<%= tb_PalavraPasse.ClientID %>').setAttribute('type', 'singleline');
    }
```

And the control that has the events:

```
<img id="img_Eye" runat="server" src="~/Recursos/Imagens/eye-icon.png" onmouseover="MouseOver_MudarTipoPassword()" onmouseout="MouseLeave_MudarTipoPassword()" />
```

So, I I've been cleaning up the code because there are functions being used on several pages and I'm combining them into a javascript file. It works like this if I put it in the head section of the page. But I want to pass an argument instead. I want to pass the textbox clientid. How can I do that?

Comment: To clarify, you want to pass the ID of the element into the function as a parameter?

Comment: Yes. I want to pass the same value it would get in the head section ('<%= tb_PalavraPasse.ClientID %>') but as a parameter from the img control.

Answer (score 2):

Make the function take a parameter:

```
function MouseOver_MudarTipoPassword(elementId) {
        document.getElementById(elementId).setAttribute('type', 'singleline');
    }
```

Pass the id into the function call:

```
<img id="img_Eye" runat="server" src="~/Recursos/Imagens/eye-icon.png" onmouseover="MouseOver_MudarTipoPassword('img_Eye')" onmouseout="MouseLeave_MudarTipoPassword('img_Eye')" />
```

> Update

Apologies, I didn't pay enough attention to the question. The problem with my answer is that the script must run before the DOM is created, like in the `HEAD`.

To make it work like you want you will have to attach an event listener to your elements. You also need a way to dynamically associate the target of the listener code. You can do that with `data-*` attributes.

[See this fiddle for working example](https://jsfiddle.net/va8Lw87k/1/)

The sample markup:

```
<input type="text" id="theTextBox" value="The IT Crowd" />
<hr />
<img id="Moss" src="https://media0.giphy.com/media/TrDxCdtmdluP6/giphy.gif" data-target="theTextBox" />
```

The 
sample javascript:

```
var test = document.getElementById("Moss");

test.addEventListener("mouseover", MouseOver_MudarTipoPassword, false);

function MouseOver_MudarTipoPassword( event ) {   
    var theImg = event.srcElement;
    var target = theImg.dataset.target; //re-use this function by applying data-target to all elements that need it (does not have to be named "target")
    document.getElementById(target).setAttribute('type', 'password');
  }
```

Comment: It doesn't work as well. The thing is, I want to pass the mouse over this image and show/hide the text in the password textbox, not the image itself, which is what you're passing as a parameter. But I tried the id of the textbox and nothing...

Comment: So use the textbox id instead of the image id.

Comment: I tested it on firefox and it doesn't work. Then I tested it on inter explorer and it works. :o Is there any other way for all browsers to support this?

Comment: Do you know exactly which part is not supported? You could always inspect the data- attribute as a regular attribute instead of using dataset property. I'm surprised it doesn't work on FF, do you have an old version?

Comment: No. It's up to date. I'm just as surprised. If were the other way around it'd fine. lol